# I lost my Silver Sword in Witcher 2

Tags: the-witcher-2

So I went and got all my stuff back from Ves in Flotsam after the drunken night I can't remember. But I never got my Silver Sword. Was it somewhere else? Is this a glitch or have I forgotten to do something?

Comment: I'm guessing you actually done the quest to get a new silver sword when you reached Flotsam? You lose it while fighting the dragon in the prologue, meaning if you never got a new one, you didnt have one to lose in the first place.

Comment: Just make another one?  The first silver sword you can make is actually better then the free one you recieve.

Answer (score 1):

You create a silver sword via crafting at a blacksmith, you first need to purchase a recipe and you will need some silver ore (naturally) among other ingredients, you can find a list of the ingredients in the recipe.